# Wordpress blog post still showing after deleting

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, posts

I'm having an issue where a blog post is still showing after being deleted. I thought the issue may have been the cache, but I already tried two different cache plugins to clear the cache, and I'm still seeing the post.

However, the strange thing is, the blog post text that I am still seeing is showing within the page (way at the bottom of the page with a ton of white space above it), yet it's not being displayed the same way the other posts are being displayed. It's like that one blog post is somehow embedded into the page, as opposed to being output in the standard post list (that can be seen at the top of the page).

Even when I go into Inspect Element, this post doesn't use the same html code as the other posts. It's not wrapped in a div with "blog_template" class. Instead, it appears to be a bunch of `<p>` tags on the page. I have no idea how that could have happened, and I can't get it to go away even after deleting the post.

[image]

The issue can be seen [here](http://www.pittsburghelderlaw.com/news-insights/).

Comment: If anyone still happens to take a look, I have added a line of css to hide those extra `<p>` tags for now, at least until I can figure out why it's still including that text in the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a query_posts function?
Try to set "post_status" => "publish" as arg